# How do I email root?

Tags: email, smtp, exim

I am on Debian squeeze and I'd like to forward my root emails to my real email. I setup exim to use gmail so when I write `mail myname@myemail.com` it sends to my email. However, now I'd like to email root and have it forward my emails to my real email address.

`mail root` does not send an email to root. If I create a different user and use the root email to that person it works. But that person or root emailing root does not. Did I break root emails? How do i fix this?

I am using exim4, which was the default.

Comment: You can move your edit to an answer (You will be able to mark it as the accepted answer later if there is no better answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to forward root's e-mails to another e-mail address, you could change the line related to root in the file `/etc/aliases`. For instance:

```
root: myname@myemail.com
```

To forward e-mails of a UNIX user (let say `myuser`) to another e-mail address (`myname@myemail.com`), had the file `.forward` in the home folder of `myuser`. This file should contain one line with the e-mail to which you would like to forward the e-mails to.

Regarding your problem with the command `mail root`, you should maybe have a look at the exim4 log files, located in `/var/log/exim4`. They may give you some clues about the problem.

Comment: Perfect answer, do you happen to know the answer to this one? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21574/how-do-i-fix-the-to-address-when-forwarding-with-mail-exim/21575#21575