# How do I fix the to address when forwarding with mail/exim?

Tags: debian, email, exim, forwarding

I am using Debian Squeeze (I believe, the box doesn't really say)
I config exim4 to use Gmail and put `root: someuser` in `/etc/aliases` then put my email address (`name+box@gmail.com`) in `.forward`.

I receive the email, however the `From:` is `user@mysite.com` which is correct, and the `To:` is `root@localhost` or `anotherUser@localhost` with name+box mentioned nowhere. I wanted to write a filter so all emails to `name+box@gmail.com` will be tagged as something, but my name is not mentioned and it goes directly to the spam folder.

How do I modify this so my name shows up in the email address?

Answer (score 3):

There is a whole [chapter](http://exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch31.html) in exim docs dedicated to address rewriting. Probably, you should add something like:

```
headers_rewrite = *@localhost $1@mysite.com t
```

to one of your transports in exim config, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I like this answer except i am not exactly trying to rewrite the to sender. I would like some way for my .forward email address to be shown in the email so i can write a filter. I guess i could just write one for anything coming from localhost

Comment: you can use `procmail` to achieve this, or add headers_rewrite to userforward router in exim config